# Acroread Convert PDF File To PostScript Segmentation Fault

Tags: linux, pdf, segmentation-fault, adobe-acrobat

Our customer has a Linux server (Redhat), which runs Java web applications. Recently there is a requirement to submit PDF files to printers to be printed out.

The command we are using is `cat /path/to/pdf_file | acroread -toPostScript | lp -dprintername`. But we are getting the error `lp: stdin is empty; so no job has been sent`.

Printing a normal file, such as /etc/hosts, using this command `lp -dprintername /etc/hosts` works, and we can see the printout at the printer. The `lp` command is not the problem.

The I proceeded to test the other 2 commands `cat /path/to/pdf_file | acroread -toPostScript` and I saw the output `Segmentation fault`.

To further troubleshoot this issue, I used the strace command like so `cat /pdf_file | strace -f -o /tmp/acroread.$$.trace acroread -toPostScript`. From the trace file, I saw these lines before the segmentation fault happened.

```
stat64("/home/oracle/.adobe", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
16673 stat64("/home/oracle/.adobe/Acrobat", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
16673 stat64("/home/oracle/.adobe/Acrobat/9.0", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
16673 stat64("/home/oracle/.adobe/Acrobat/9.0/Temp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
16673 open("/home/oracle/.adobe/Acrobat/9.0/Temp/AdobeTempPS7XwXNz", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 4
16673 close(4)                          = 0
16673 unlink("/home/oracle/.adobe/Acrobat/9.0/Temp/AdobeTempPS7XwXNz") = 0
16673 open("/home/oracle/.adobe/Acrobat/9.0/Temp/AdobeTempPS7XwXNz", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 4
16673 getcwd("/var/spool/mail"..., 1024) = 16
16673 open("/home/oracle/.adobe/Acrobat/9.0/Temp/AdobeTempPS7XwXNz", O_RDONLY) = 5
16673 --- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
16673 +++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
16720 <... waitpid resumed> 0x3, WNOHANG|WCONTINUED|0x7410) = 0
```

When I did an listing of the /home/oracle/.adobe/Acrobat/9.0/Temp/ directory, all the files are zero byte size.

So, my question is what could have caused the segmentation fault? Is it a bug in this version of Acrobat Reader?

The Acrobat Reader version installed is 9.4.

The RedHat version is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 (Tikanga). The kernel is Linux SCHPOAPS1 2.6.18-274.el5 #1 SMP Fri Jul 8 17:36:59 EDT x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Comment: `lp`? What old version of Red Hat is this?

Comment: I have updated the question with the redhat and kernel version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed this by removing the current Acrobat Reader (ver 9.4), and installing a higher version one (9.5.5).

Answer (score 0):

I think, that it is acroread problem, when it want to open file `/home/oracle/.adobe/Acrobat/9.0/Temp/AdobeTempPS7XwXNz` twice.

Can you use `pdf2ps` instead of `acroread`?

Comment: If there are no other solutions, we might give this a try. Thanks.